# CPLEX read excel by index

Tags: cplex

How can I read a tuple from excel on cplex by its index note the cell.
I mean :

```
T from SheetRead(sheet,"'Data'!(0,0)");
```

Instead of :

```
T from SheetRead(sheet,"'Data'!A1");
```

I have tuple that can be longer or shorter between different simulation. The lenght is define by n. May I do a thing like :

```
T from SheetRead(sheet,"'Data'!(0,0):(0,n)");
```

thank have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to your questions can be found in the [reference documentation of function `SheetRead`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_opl_SheetRead.html):

1. Usually, you can use Excel's R1C1 notation to index cells purely by index. Unfortunately, this is not supported by OPL.
2. The arguments to function `SheetRead` can only be string literals. So you cannot use variables there.

One option in your case would be to define a named range in the Excel sheets. For example, you can define a named range called "TupleData" in each of the different sheets and define that range to be of different dimension/location in different sheets. Then in the `.dat` file you can write

```
T from SheetRead(sheet, "'Data'!TupleData");
```

Comment: First of all, thank you
i don't quite understand, how can I call something in excel tupledata and that can be 
instantiated in cplex ?
I mean what
`T from SheetRead(sheet, "'Data'!TupleData");`
will call ?

Comment: What I am talking about are "named ranges" in Excel. You may want to google this to learn about this. In Excel you can assign a name to a range. For example, you can say that the range A1:C10 should be referred to as "TupleData". Once you have this symbolic name for the range you can access the range by this name.

Comment: Yes you right sorry, and then OPL is able to call it.
Ok tank you sir ! have a good day